# Delete 0s that occur only at the beginning of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list which has 0s at the beginning I want to delete. 0s do occur elsewhere in the data but I want to keep these.

```
l=[0, 0, 0, 0, 151, 199, 149, 147, 281, 133, 166, 162, 0, 353, 867, 1060, 525, 1031, 420, 0, 832, 1114, 869, 531, 546, 555, 520, 679, 715, 669, 555, 888, 605, 809, 0, 514]
```

needs to become:

```
l=[151, 199, 149, 147, 281, 133, 166, 162, 0, 353, 867, 1060, 525, 1031, 420, 0, 832, 1114, 869, 531, 546, 555, 520, 679, 715, 669, 555, 888, 605, 809, 0, 514]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to drop those zeros:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
import operator

l = list(dropwhile(operator.not_, l))
```

This will drop *just* the initial 0 values; or rather, all false-y values, using [`operator.not_()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.not_).

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> import operator
>>> l=[0, 0, 0, 0, 151, 199, 149, 147, 281, 133, 166, 162, 0, 353, 867, 1060, 525, 1031, 420, 0, 832, 1114, 869, 531, 546, 555, 520, 679, 715, 669, 555, 888, 605, 809, 0, 514]
>>> list(dropwhile(operator.not_, l))
[151, 199, 149, 147, 281, 133, 166, 162, 0, 353, 867, 1060, 525, 1031, 420, 0, 832, 1114, 869, 531, 546, 555, 520, 679, 715, 669, 555, 888, 605, 809, 0, 514]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the methods list.index() and next():

```
L=[0, 0, 1, 2, 'a', 3, 0, 0, 9]

noLeadingZeros = L[L.index(next(i for i in L if i!=0)):]
```